# We can't give the structure of linear space on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ for a set of rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help me prove, that we can't give the structure of a linear space over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ for a set of rational numbers with standard addition operation.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a field of numbers $(a + b\sqrt{2}), \text{where  } a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$

**Edit**

We can assume, that in this case "1" is a neutral element for multiplication? The neutral element must be defined along with field definition or operation definition and I have freedom to choose it?

Comment: 1 is the neutral element of the field ${\bf Q}(\sqrt2)$ so it must be the neutral element for scalar multiplication in any linear structure.

Comment: isn't it a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write scalar multiplication as #. Let $\sqrt2\#1=p/q$. Then $\sqrt2\#q=p$, so $\sqrt2\#(\sqrt2\#q)=\sqrt2\#p=p^2/q$. But $\sqrt2\#(\sqrt2\#q)=(\sqrt2\sqrt2)\#q=2\#q=(1+1)\#q=2q$. So $p^2/q=2q$, contradiction.

Comment: Ok, so we need to prove, that there not exist any valid multiplication?

Comment: Well, the standard addition passes all the tests, so the only place anything could possibly go wrong is with the multiplication. Yes, you have to show that there is no way to define the multiplication that meets the axioms of a linear space.

Answer (score 0):

In a vector field sturcture, there are given 'scalar' type entities and 'vector' type entities. Now scalars are elements of the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and vectors should be elements in some $U\subseteq \Bbb Q$, if I am right.

$1$ is present in the field, and of course acts as unit, but multiplying vector by vector is not defined.

The main point is, that if $v\in U\subseteq\Bbb Q$, and $x\in \Bbb Q\subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, then
$x\cdot v$ in this vector space structure has to be $x\cdot v$. You can see this by writing $x=n/m$.

And therefore all $\Bbb Q$ is used up with a given $v\ne 0$, and then, "there is no more space for" $\sqrt 2\cdot v$, though this should differ to all $x\cdot v$ for $x\in\Bbb Q$.